# Advantage of the interrupt when there is a busy waiting?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32ldiscovery

I know the specific of the busy waiting and interrupt separately but not sure what is the benefit when we use interrupt in the busy waiting loop.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Can you rephrase what you mean for that ?